# Are Kalman Filter innovations and state errors independent?

Tags: independence, kalman-filter

I have questions about the Kalman Filter.

I know that the Kalman Filter residual is independent with the state error, which are defined as:

Kalman Filter residual : $r_k=z_k - H_k x ̂_k^+ $

state error : $e_k=x ̂_k^+ - x_k$

where $z_k$ is measurement, $H_k$ is measurement model, $x ̂_k^+$ is the Kalman Filter *a posteriori* estimate, and $x_k$ is the true state value.

Then, is the Kalman Filter innovation, which is defined as below, is independent with the state error?

Kalman Filter innovation : $a_k = z_k - H_kx ̂_k^-$

where $x ̂_k^-$ is the Kalman Filter *a priori* estimate

I think it is not, but I found a paper that says they are independent.

Thank you